# MVC 4 form dellemma

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have a problem that I cnt seem to figure out, take into consideration that i only started with web development 3 weeks ago.
I have a request application where a user will be presented with a form to create a request.
Now on the admin side the administrator must be able to create new form templates that will get rendered to the user. This entails creating new form fields with predefined options.

Im stuck now, is there a workaround to this problem, how do I add new forms from the admin side and display the form without having created the model?

Here is how im currently displaying the form to the users

In my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var context = new ITISS_RequestEntities();

        var temp = from r in context.RequestTypes
                   select r.TypeDescription;
        var list = temp.ToList();
        var newReq = new RequestName();
        var selectList = context.RequestTypes.ToList().Select(t => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = t.TypeDescription,
            Value = t.RequestType1.ToString()
        });
        newReq.isto = selectList;

        ViewData["data"] = selectList;

        return View(newReq);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateForm(string s)
    {
        var fieldId = SqlRequestType(int.Parse(s));
        var entries = new List<List<string>>();
        var list = new List<string>();
        var type = new List<string>();
        var dbs = new List<string>();
        var envs = new List<string>();

        var context = new ITISS_RequestEntities();
        foreach (var item in fieldId)
        {
            var fields = context.FieldDefinitions.Where(f => f.RequestField == item).Select(f => f.FieldName);
            var types = context.FieldDefinitions.Where(f => f.RequestField == item).Select(f => f.ControlType);
            var entryContext = context.EntryDefinitions.Where(e => e.RequestField == item).Select(e => e.EntryName);

            var entryList = entryContext.ToList();
            entries.Add(entryList);
            var firstOrDefault = types.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstOrDefault != null) type.Add(firstOrDefault);
            var orDefault = fields.FirstOrDefault();
            if (orDefault != null) list.Add(orDefault);
        }

        var component = from c in context.Components
                        select c.ComponentName;

        var components = component.ToList();


        ViewBag.entries = entries;
        ViewBag.components = components;
        ViewBag.type = type;
        ViewBag.list = list;

        return PartialView("_formUpdate", list);
    }
```

Here is my view
        @model ItissBootstrap.Models.RequestName
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        }

```
    <h2>Create new request</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("data", null, new { @onChange = "test(this.value)" })

        <div id="PartialView"></div>
        <div style="float:right"><input type="submit" value="Submit Request" /></div>

    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(i) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateForm", "Request")',
                data: { s: i },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $('#PartialView').html(data);
                }
            });
         }
    </script>
```

Here is my partial view

```
    @model List<string>

    @{
        List<List<string>> e = ViewBag.entries;
        List<string> l = ViewBag.list;
        List<string> t = ViewBag.type;
        List<string> c = ViewBag.components;
        var ud = new ItissBootstrap.Models.UserDetails();
    }
    @for (var i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Label(l[i]);
        switch (t[i])
        {
             case "Dropdown":
                if (e[i].Count > 0)
                {
                    var sl = new SelectList(
                        e[i].Select(x => new
                        {
                            value = x,
                            text = x
                        }),
                        "value",
                        "text");
                    @Html.DropDownList("value", sl)
                }
                if (l[i] == "Database Name")
                {
                    var sl = new SelectList(
                        ud.Databases.Select(x => new
                        {
                            value = x,
                            text = x
                        }),
                        "value",
                        "text");
                    @Html.DropDownList("value", sl)
                }
                if (l[i] == "Environment")
                {
                    var sl = new SelectList(
                        ud.environments.Select(x => new
                        {
                            value = x,
                            text = x
                        }),
                        "value",
                        "text");
                    @Html.DropDownList("value", sl)
                }
                if (l[i] == "Component")
                {
                    var sl = new SelectList(
                        c.Select(x => new
                        {
                            value = x,
                            text = x
                        }),
                        "value",
                        "text");
                    @Html.DropDownList("value", sl)
                }
                break;
            case "Text":
                @Html.TextArea("new")
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem, it sounds like a specification. I don't think anyone's going to design an application for you.

Comment: If the admin creates a new form there is no model to bind to the view the user sees. How can I then create a dynamic model to bind to the new view

Comment: Well in that case you're right, you do have a problem. So why didn't you include that in your question? Add more details, including how forms are created and built, and how you're currently handling the POST method with code samples if possible